# Unix file comparison

Tags: unix, awk, file-comparison

I have two files which has component name and version number separated by a space:

```
cat file1
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.9
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65

cat file2 
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.0.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
com.acc.invm:distri_cob 110
```

needed output is: All components from file2 with a higher version than in file1.

We have to ignore components from file2 if that is not in file1, and components with same version and lower version in file1.

In this example the desired output is

```
 com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
 com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
 com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
```

Hope so I am clear with my requirement.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ split($2,a,/\./); curr = a[1]*10000 + a[2]*100 + a[3] }
NR==FNR { prev[$1] = curr; next }
!($1 in prev) || (curr > prev[$1])

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65
```

Comment: How its "tst.awk" file made?

Comment: With your text editor of choice, just like any other file. vi, emacs, pico, whatever... How did you create your files?

Comment: Ed Morton above logic is working fine, But want to make 1 more file which is having data as:

Components which is in file1 is present in file2 with higher version. In above example desired out is:

com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10

Hope so I am clear with my requirement.
could you please help.

Comment: No, you need to post sample input and expected output, properly formatted in a question. I suggest you post a new question and refer to this one but still have the new question stand alone with all relevant info.

Comment: I have raised a new question and updated this question also.
Please help

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution which is "almost there":

```
join -a1 file1 file2 | awk '$2 > $3 {print $1,$2}'
```

It produces:

```
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.9
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65
```

Note that the BDMap entry is produced because awk doesn't know how to parse your version numbers, so they're compared textually.  If you could use version numbers with fixed numbers of digits like 100.000.009 this would fix it, but I suppose you don't want to do that so we'll need to work on the above a little more.

Comment: Thanks John but my requirement is, it should be depend on version also.

    all components from file1 with a higher version than in file2.
    all components in file1 which are not in file2.

BDMap not supposed be in o/p because it is having lower version(100.0.9) in file1 comparatively file2.

Comment: @RakeshSinghTomar: Yes and if you read what I wrote you can see my full discussion of exactly those issues.  You should integrate the version tokenizing code you already have into my awk program, and then it should be complete.  The main point of my answer is that a big part of the work can be done much more easily with `join` before `awk`.